# How to fill same data to selected rectangle cells in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Is it there a easy way to fill the same data in the rectangle area from cell `a` to cell `b` (4x4 cells) in the org-mode table as shown below in one go?

```
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   | a |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   | b |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

Comment: Not too clear. Are you asking to copy the content of cell a to cell b, overwriting any content that might be there already? Or to move it? Or something else? (Usually "fill" in Emacs means filling text to fit lines with a `fill-column`, but I don't think you are asking about that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the following code does what you want.
Select the rectangle from `a` to `b` in your table and call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-table-copy-corner-to-rectangle`.
All fields inside the rectangle are filled with `a`.
You can put the code into your init-file (e.g., `~/.emacs`) and bind some key or menu-entry to it. Adding a menu item to the Tbl menu is already included at the end of the following code.

```lisp
(require 'org-table)
(defun org-table-copy-corner-to-rectangle  ()
  "Copy the field at the start corner of the currently active rectangle to the full rectangle."
  (interactive)
  (unless (org-region-active-p)
    (error "Active region in org-table required"))
  (let* ((beg (region-beginning))
     (end (region-end)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char beg)
      (org-table-check-inside-data-field)
      (let* ((field (save-excursion (org-table-get-field)))
         (l01 (org-table-current-dline))
         (c01 (org-table-current-column))
         (l02 (progn (goto-char end)
             (org-table-check-inside-data-field)
             (org-table-current-dline)))
         (c02 (org-table-current-column))
         (cMin (min c01 c02))
         (cMax (max c01 c02))
         (nl (abs (- l01 l02))))
    (goto-char beg)
    (loop for row from 0 upto nl do
          (while (org-at-table-hline-p) (beginning-of-line 2))
          (if (not (org-at-table-p))
          (progn (end-of-line 0) (org-table-next-field)))
          (loop for col from cMin upto cMax do
            (org-table-goto-column col nil 'force)
            (org-table-get-field nil field))
          (forward-line)))
      (goto-char beg)
      (org-table-align))))

(easy-menu-add-item org-tbl-menu '("Rectangle") ["Copy start corner to rectangle" org-table-copy-corner-to-rectangle :active (org-at-table-p)])
```